# I want to use part of the source file name as the file name in the sink folder. "Azure Synapse Analytics"

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-synapse, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am trying to unzip a Zip folder with 21 files in the Synapse pipeline and create a folder with each file name and put each file in there.
Example
sorce: zipfolder/zipfiles(SRI W 01 maker メーカー.zip and SRI W 02 product_name 製品名.zip)/files(SRI W 01 maker メーカー.csv and SRI W 02 product_name 製品名.csv)

I tried the below answer but the error occurred.
I attached the screenshot of error messeage.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNZjn.png)

*"メーカー","製品名" are Japanese.

sink: SRI W 01 maker(folder)/SRI W 01 maker.csv
SRI W 02 product_name(folder)/SRI W 02 product_name.csv
*I want to remove the Japanese part.

This is an example of file structure, and the actual file names contain Japanese characters.
The actual file name is
"SRI W 01 maker maker", which has a space and Japanese characters at the end, resulting in garbled characters.
I would like to remove this Japanese part and create the folder and file names dynamically.

Sorry for the poor explanation.
If necessary, I can give you screenshots and other information.

Source dataset is here:
1.Zipped folder.(It has 21 zip files.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OG4j9.png)

2.21 zip files under the Zip folder.
(Each of them has one file containing Japanese.)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MjBa.png)

3.Example of a file containing Japanese.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBpt6.png)

Comment: Are the japanese words always at the end of the file name?

Answer (score 0):

I have broken the requirements into 2 parts. The ***reason*** is because my local machine does not allow me to zip a file consisting non-English characters (for reproducing the requirement).

**1. Creating a pipeline to unzip the main zip file.**

- Upload your zip file to storage account and use the following procedure. In this, I have considered the same storage account as source and sink as well.
- Using copy data activity, create a binary dataset for source. Set compression type as `ZipDeflate` for this dataset. In the source tab, *check the `recursively` checkbox*.

**UPDATE:**
Please make sure that the copy data activity settings are identical to the one given in the following image.

- Source settings:

[image]

- Source dataset:

[image]

- Sink settings:

[image]

- Sink dataset:

[image]

- For destination, create a binary dataset as well, and specify a name in folder field. It creates a folder, where your sub zip folders will be decompressed (I have given its value as `repro1407`). Run the pipeline and the following is the output it creates.

[image]

- The following folders inside `repro1407`, each with a file containing Japanese characters (I had to manually upload a file containing Japanese characters because of the above specified reason)

[image]

**2. Creating a pipeline to remove the Japanese characters.**

- Now this part will help you remove unwanted characters from the file names inside the folders (in above image).
- After the above process the folders are structured as:

```
`repro1407 -> {country_data.zip -> {SRI W 01 maker メーカー.csv}, person.zip -> {SRI W 02 product_name 製品名.csv}}`
```

- Use a `Get Metadata activity` to get the names of folders in `repro1407` by creating a dataset pointing to it and selecting Field List as `child items`. Give the output of `Get Metadata` to `ForEach` activity and give items value as **@activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems**

[image]

- Inside `ForEach`, use `set variable` to create a variable `folder_name` (String type) to set folder name by giving its value as **@item().name**. Connect it to another `Get Metadata` activity where create a dataset using dynamic content for folder as **@concat('repro1407','/',item().name)**. (Field list is child items). Create `execute pipeline` activity as shown below:

[image]

- In below image of execute pipeline activity which invokes `for` pipeline, the highlighted parameters are parameters inside `for` pipeline and we are passing values from this pipeline (Had to use execute pipeline because we need to execute nested foreach because of nested folders, and nested for are not supported, have to create execute pipeline):

[image]

- Inside `for` pipeline, there is a direct `ForEach` activity whose items value is **@pipeline().parameters.file_names** (list of file names inside `folder_name` folder) which we passed from previous pipeline. Inside foreach, there are 3 activities.
- The first set variable `split_file` (Array) is to split the currect file name (there is only one). Since there are spaces between file name so, I used split using `' '`. The value to be set is **@split(item().name,' ')**

[image]

- The second set variable `japanese` is to get the the japanese character. Since it is occuring at the end of the file, use **@last(variables('split_file'))** value to get it using `last()` on the `split_file` array.

[image]

- The last is a copy data activity. I am saving the renamed file in the same folder it is taken from. Create source and sink datasets (open dataset -> Parameters and create). Create 2 parameters each for these datasets. `folder_structure` and `ip_name` for source dataset and `folder_struct` and `output_name` for sink dataset (To use them as path).
- Values to be passed for `folder_structure` is **@concat('repro1407','/',pipeline().parameters.folder_name)** and for `ip_name` it is **@item().name**

[image]

- Similarly values of sink dataset for `output_name` is **@concat(replace(item().name,variables('japanese'),''),'.csv')** and for `folder_struct` is **@concat('repro1407','/',pipeline().parameters.folder_name)**

[image]

The following is how you use these values in datasets:

- Source dataset:

[image]

- Sink dataset:

[image]

Publish and run the pipeline. It runs successfully and generates the the required output. The following is an image inside one folder (Every folder would reflect in the same way.)

[image]

**NOTE:**

- If you don't need the original file (with Japanese characters), you can simply add delete activity and use dynamic content to delete the original file.
- If the Japanese characters are not always at the end of the file name, then you have to find a pattern that can be applied to all the 21 sub-folders. This logic needs to be appiled on the `set variable` activities inside `ForEach` activity of `for` pipeline.

Comment: I was able to complete the process even with Azure datalake gen2 storage (with zip files having japanese characters just as yours). I have added to my answer 1. the source and sink settings 2. dataset settings. Please consider following them.